# When I change specific cell value to specific value then write

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have make an attempt to create this code and it is working fine but it writes the timestamp whenever `Col"B"` any values changes to specific value.

I just want that when cell value changes from `Approved` to `Reject` then write timestamp.

It should not work when `other values` changed to `Reject`.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var editedColumn = e.range.getSheet().getActiveCell().getColumn();
  
  if(sheet=="Sheet1"){
  if(e.value=="Approved" && editedColumn==2 ){
  
    e.range.offset(0,12).setValue(new Date ()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

  }}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
e.value=="Approved" && editedColumn==2
```

use

```
e.oldValue=="Approved" && e.value=="Reject" && editedColumn==2
```

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events